# Production Cookie shows up in Development and Staging

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

This bug is not currently causing any issues.

```
OS: macOS
Browser: Chrome
Framework: Next.js
```

```
Production url: example.yes
Staging url: example-staging.herokuapp.com
Development: localhost
```

Cookies for the production website show up in my staging and development environments. But not for all paths.

In development the following production cookie is present at localhost:3000/a_route,

```
Name      Domain        Path
token     example.yes   /
```

But the same cookie is not available at all urls in development. For example there is no production cookie at localhost:3000/another_route.

In staging the same production cookie is present at https://example-staging.herokuapp.com/a_route,

```
Name      Domain        Path
token     example.yes   /
```

I'm setting cookies myself sometimes on the client (React) and sometimes on the server (Next.js). Any insight into why this is happening would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried to delete all cookies for all domains?

Comment: Yeah. This situation reproduces itself every time.